# Migration from Swift 2.3 to 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, cocoapods

I am trying to migrate from Swift 2.3 to 3.0. I am using XCode 8.3.2. I can update my code to Swift 3.0, however I am using Cocoapods to install few third party libraries which are written in Swift 2.3. These third party libraries are not yet upgraded to Swift 3.0 by the current maintainers.

I tried to set the configuration to 2.3 in podFile as shown below, but it is not helping. Is there a way to migrate my project code alone to Swift 3.0, pods with Swift 2.3 and build the code? Is this possible? I checked in multiple forums, but did not get much info.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'LatestSwiftMigration' do

    pod 'XXXXXXXXX', '~> 1.4'


end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Pretty sure your question is identical to the linked dupe.  If you don't find your answer, ping me and I'll reopen.

Comment: @JAL I can't find the answer.

Comment: You need to fork the pods and manually update them to Swift 3.  You can't use a binary built with Swift 2.3 with Swift 3.0.